# Adding another language to chrome

Tags: google-chrome, programming-languages, virtual-machine

I've just recently built a programming language and I want to integrate it into chrome so it can not only be mixed with html but also interact with the lower levels of chrome (io, bluetooth, etc). What would be the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can try NPAPI to develop a Google Chrome native plugin. However, it is not recommended because of the security problem.
https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/npapi

You can also build a native client with the SDK
https://developers.google.com/native-client/dev/?csw=1

Comment: NPAPI support is expected to be removed this year, and I believe it's already impossible to distribute new extensions containing NPAPI plugins, so NPAPI is definitely not the right approach. Also, NPAPI is a poor choice for integrating with Chrome internals since the API between the plugin and the browser is very limited.